# .gitignore from parentmodule does not apply to submodules?

Tags: git, gitignore

**SO advises against deleting answered question so I will leave this here but please see John's answer which explains that the explanation is already present in the text a quoted.**

According to the manpage it seems git commands would go up the directory hierarchy up to the root directory:

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file in the same directory as the
>   path, or in any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level
>   files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those
>   in lower level files down to the directory containing the file.

Our project has many git submodules and I was hoping to be able to use a single .gitignore in the parentmodules that can apply to all of them.

But that doesn't seem to work. Does the search for .gitignore stop at the repository root? I am hoping I am making a mistake.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.5.5
$ grep target ../.gitignore # the .gitignore in the parent module
target
**/target/
$ git status --porcelain # feature/target/ matches **/target but is not ignored 
?? feature/target/
?? update-site/target/
$ echo '**/target/' >> .gitignore # add it to submodule repo root
$ git status --porcelain
M .gitignore
```

Comment: I'm facing a very similar issue and the accepted answer did not help me. As a workaround, I created a `.gitignore` file in the submodule folder and did not commit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search for a `.gitignore` does stop at the repository root. The docs you posted say as much themselves ("up to the top level of the work tree"). This doesn't work any differently for submodules as for any other repositories.

If you want the same ignore rules across the repositories, you need to either check the same `.gitignore` into each repo, or use global ignore rules (but of course those would be specific to your local machine; you can't check them in).

Comment: I managed to ignore the part about work tree :) Guess I only read what I wanted to read. Thanks for the quick reply, but ima delete this question